# Liberar botão depois de certa data

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $date = date('Y-m-d');

  if ($date >= '<?php the_sub_field("data"); ?>') { ?>

  <!-- Se a data for maior -->
  <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_da_lista'); ?>">
  <button class="btn btn-success"><?php the_sub_field("nome_da_lista"); ?></button>
  </a>

 <?php } else { ?>
<!-- Se a data for menor -->
  <button class="btn btn-disabled" disabled><?php the_sub_field("nome_da_lista"); ?></button>
  <?php  } 
?>
```

Estou desenvolvendo um portal para alunos, e preciso criar um botão que seja liberado após certa data que o administrador colocar. Estou usando *WordPress* e um plugin chamado *ACF - Advanced Custom Fields*

**Código:**

```
<?php if(get_field('lista_de_exame')): ?>
  <?php while(has_sub_field('lista_de_exame')): ?>
          <?php
              date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
              $date = date('Y-m-d');

              if ($date >= '<?php the_sub_field("data); ?>') { ?>

              <!-- Se a data for maior -->
              <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_da_lista'); ?>">
              <button class="btn btn-success"><?php the_sub_field("nome_da_lista"); ?></button>
              </a>

             <?php } else { ?>
            <!-- Se a data for menor -->
              <button class="btn btn-disabled" disabled><?php the_sub_field("nome_da_lista"); ?></button>
              <?php  } 
          ?>
```

Porém, quando coloco a data pelo painel do *WordPress*, não tenho resposta do *script*.

Comment: Não tem necessidade de usar isso `<?php the_sub_field("data); ?>`, bastaria apenas usar a função (sem passar a abertura/fechado da tag do *PHP*).

Comment: Já tentei e mesmo assim não retorna a data

Comment: Substitua `'<?php the_sub_field("data"); ?>'` por `get_sub_field("nome_do_campo_criado")`

Comment: Mas vai depender do formato que está o campo de data que você criou.

Comment: Criei o campo Seletor de Datas

Comment: Valdeir, muito obrigado pela ajuda, consegui fazer roda, era uma coisinha simples kkkkk so trocar o the por get